Rational function raised to irrational power. Is the result an irrational function?
Let $P$ and $Q$ be polynomials over $\mathbb R$ such that the rational function $P/Q$ is not constant. Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. Is it possible that $(P/Q)^\alpha$ is a rational function? I expect not, but on the other hand, it is well known that a rational number raised to an irrational power can be rational. So perhaps something similar is possible in this case.
EDIT:
Definition. A function $f$ is said to be a rational function if it can be written as $f = R/S$ for two polynomials $R$ and $S$.
Ultimately, I would like to answer this question for multivariate polynomials, but I would already be quite happy to understand the univariate case.

What do you mean by "rational function"?

@badjohn A function $f$ is a rational function if it can be written as $f = R/S$ for two polynomials $R$ and $S$.

I was checking that you did not mean one which takes the rationals to the rationals.  Your mention that an irrational power of a rational might be rational suggested that you might be using this other definition.

@badjohn Good point, I will clarify this in the question

Are the polynomials univariate?

@Amateur_Algebraist Ultimately, no. But I would already be quite happy to understand the univariate case.

By Yves Daoust's answer, the degrees of $P$ and $Q$ are equal. Assume $P$ and $Q$ have no common factors, i.e., their roots are distinct.
Then, your question is whether there are polynomials $R$ and $S$ (again wlog without common factors) such that
$$\left(\frac{P}{Q}\right)^\alpha=\frac{R}{S}\\\Longleftrightarrow \quad P^\alpha S=Q^\alpha R\,.$$
So $R$ has exactly the same roots as $P^\alpha$. Around one of these roots, $R\sim x^p$ for some multiplicity $p$, while $P^\alpha\sim x^{q\alpha}$. is $\alpha$ is irrational, this doesn't work.
Hence, the answer is no.

The function $R:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $R(x)=\tfrac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}$ doesn't have any zeros, so that one cannot arrive at a contradiction by comparing asymptotic behavior around the zeros

@KBDave Be $R$, I mean a polynomial, not the rational function. And the argument works for complex roots as well.
